# Can radiotherapy cause "chemo brain"?

Tags: cancer

As above, can radiotherapy cause "chemo brain"? For example, can radiation treatment for prostate cancer cause "[chemo brain](https://www.livestrong.org/we-can-help/finishing-treatment/cognitive-changes-after-cancer-treatment)" years later?

Comment: Although you have a valid question in the title, the rest of the question pertains to a specific person and medical advice is strictly off topic here. I think your question can be edited to comply, but doing so would mainly be a matter of deleting 90% of your question. I'm reluctant to do such a drastic edit, so you're going to need to do it  in order to avoid having your question closed.

Comment: Understood. Not looking for medical advice, only really to find out what the question says. The rest is more for background info. Completely understand and don't expect medical advice. If you have to edit it, go ahead.